# Adjusted ICC with mixed effects model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation

I am trying to run an intraclass correlation for a small dataset, adjusting for the interval of time between sessions, which varied across participants. In the data below, value is the dependent variable, session is my grouping variable, and interval is the covariate I would like to adjust for. I found the rpt funtion, which calculates adjusted ICC using generalized linear mixed-effects models, but I don't think I am setting the model up correctly?

```
library(lme4)
library(rptR)

fit = lmer(value~interval+(1|session),data=df)
rpt(fit, session, data = df, adjusted = TRUE, datatype = c("Gaussian"), npermut = 10)
```

This gives the following error:

> Error in names(var_a) <- grname : 'names' attribute [20] must be the
>   same length as the vector [0]

Data:

```
subject <- c("S002","S003","S006","S010","S011","S004","S005","S008","S007","S009","S002","S003","S006","S010","S011","S004","S005","S008","S007","S009")
group <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
interval <- c(392,428,396,310,252,299,236,202,203,126,392,428,396,310,252,299,236,202,203,126)
session <- c("test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest","retest")
value <- c(1.806574,1.755773,1.995925,1.694648,1.719913,1.419723,1.586525,1.769492,1.340397,1.447161,1.780766,1.690573,2.000000,1.476908,1.738115,1.000000,1.328443,1.655800,1.312143,1.388481)
df <- data.frame(subject, group, interval, session, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is in the rpt() call.
Try replacing

```
fit
```

with the actual model

```
value~interval+(1|session)
```

and replace the group-name (grname)

```
session
```

with

```
grname="session"
```

Please try this and confirm if this works.